# Download with iGetter stops and hangs after a 97% complete

Tags: download, osx-leopard, download-manager, file-download

I'm using iGetter 2.8.7 to download Netbeans 6.8, the size of which is 145.02 MBs. I've tried it multiple times and every time it stops when it has downloaded 97% of that file.

The speed gradually decreases to 0 KB/s and every 10 minutes or so it starts downloading again at a few Bytes per second, which is not much.

The URL of the file that I'm downloading is:
http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/6.8/final/bundles/netbeans-6.8-ml-java-macosx.dmg

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you download other files with it? And can you download the same file without iGetter?

Comment: Yes, I download other files with iGetter, and not the same file with other tools. Looks like there's a problem with the link huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some kind of issue with the Netbeans 6.8 installer, as discussed [on this thread](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic20818.html).